# Sterling Numbers of The Second Kind With Limitations Placed on Boxes/Parts

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, faq

I know there are similar problems already on the board. However, none of the previously stated questions contain problems where limitations are placed on the BOXES.

Thus, seeing that I am struggling with finding answers to these limitation questions, here is a  generalization of different cases of combinatorics problems that I have come across.

A general way of arranging M Distinct Objects into N Identical Boxes With Limitations. i.e (Sterling Numbers of The Second Kind With Limitations placed On Boxes).

## Case 1:

Distribute M-Distinct balls into N-Identical Boxes where there are atleast K Boxes that are NOT EMPTY.

Example: S(5,3); where there are ATLEAST 3 boxes that are Not Empty.

## Case 2:

Distribute M-Distinct balls into N-Identical Boxes where there are atmost K Boxes that are NOT EMPTY.

Example: S(5,3); where there are at most 3 boxes that are Not Empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sterling numbers of the second kind, e.g. S(5,3) count partitions of a set of 5 objects into 3 blocks, where none of the boxes are empty. What you're suggesting has 3 parameters, say S(n,m,k), a partition of a set of n objects into at most m blocks where at least k are used. But that would just be $\sum_{i=k}^{m} S(n,i)$; the possible number of blocks used goes from k to m, and from there, it's just Sterling numbers of the second kind.

Your second case, if I understand correctly, would just be the number of partitions of a set of n objects into at most k parts, in which case the m isn't really relevant unless m < k. If k $\leq$ m, then it's just $\sum_{i=1}^{k} S(n,i)$. If m < k, then the sum just goes from 1 to m. Either way, you never use more than k parts.

Comment: I appreciate the response Kevin, I myself just discovered that the First Case is indeed a summation of the sterling numbers up to K. However, I did not find the Second Case. I'm grateful for your help.